# How to use older sqlite version in iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite, version, preload

I want to use a previous version of sqlite in my iOS app as I have a collation in my database that is deprecated with the new version of sqlite that iOS comes with.

I haven't seen anywhere this is asked or a solution talked about and i'm not sure where to start other then I think I need to preload the sqlite version with the app upon download but as to tell the app to not use the main iOS sqlite and use the preloaded one, I really have no idea.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: It might be better to use the latest SQLite and either use a non-deprecated collation (which one?) or implement your own custom collation so you don't need to worry about the deprecated one.

Comment: That was my first desire but i'm not in control of how the project is to be done and this is what is required. But the collation is one specially built for the project and it's not up to me to swap it out! But thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you go to http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/sqlite/ in the downloads tab, you can find some versions of sqlite, thier sorces, and some binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and compile your own version of SQLite into your project. Compile the amalgamation into a target, then link that as a dependency to your main project in Xcode.